# htaccess url rewrite many links and protect css and js files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url, seo

I want to rewrite my links but with multi styles
 here is i want i want to be look like

**Info** cms is my Rewrite Base

**Cats style**
     http://www.site.com/catname

**Post Style** 
     http://www.site.com/anycatname/posttitle

**Pages Style**
     http://www.site.com/page/page+title+here

My Pages is

cats style  => cats.php?name=catname

posts style => posts.php?title=posttitle

page style  => page.php?name=catname

**Note**

As I tried to make url rewrite as in posts style css and js files had many problem too

Comment: What do you have in your htaccess file so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below url

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

or try below

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/([^/]+).zip /download.php?section=$1&file=$2 [NC]
```

would allow you to present this link as..

```
mysite/files/games/hoopy.zip
```

and in the background have that transparently translated, server-side, to..

```
mysite/download.php?section=games&file=hoopy
```